# Link Dynamic library to Netbeans Platform Project

Tags: macos, ubuntu, netbeans, platform

Sorry if this is a beginner question but I am trying to solve this for many hours without success.

I have a problem getting a platform netbeans project (contains number of modules suits) to run in Ubuntu or Mac.

In Ubuntu 18.04, if I run the project from launcher it raises an error related to a missing dynamic library. I tried to add the missing library path to the system e.g. .bashrc but this solve the problem partly. The project now runs only if I start netbeans from the terminal.

I tried to add the path globally e.g. in /etc/ld.so.conf.d but this does not work.

Same error happens in Mac OS but starting netbeans from the terminal does not solve the problem.

It same netbeans platform project does not have properties or option to add dynamic library e.g. .so file.

Comment: You can set an environment variable in .profile instead of .bashrc on Ubuntu log out and back in and it should be set  without running from a terminal. You could also edit script netbeans uses to launch.

Comment: Souns like you *linked* ok, but dyld can't find the lib when you launch.  Have you inspected the installed paths using `otool -L /path/to/mac/exec` yet?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried .profile but it didn't work as well. I have no access to mac now so I will try the mac comment next week.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It still does not work in Ubuntu. What do you mean by exec? netbeans?  the project usually run with:  ant -f path / to / myproject   the error message: Failed to load one or more dynamic libraries for myproject  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  no myprojectDepsLibJavaJNI in java.library.path

Comment: in ubuntu I had to soft link the libraries to the system lib folder:   for a in \myprojectdeps\lib\* ; do sudo ln -s \myprojectdeps\lib/$a /usr/lib/$a ;done

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me:

In Ubuntu: soft link the libraries to the system lib folder e.g.

```
 for a in \myprojectdeps\lib* ; do sudo ln -s \myprojectdeps\lib/$a /usr/lib/$a ;done
```

In Mac:  soft link the libraries to the user Java lib folder

```
   for a in \myprojectdeps\lib* ; do ln -s \myprojectdeps\lib/$a ~/Library/Java/Extensions/$a ;done
```